# get value input radio button javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an input type radio button for user to choose one value, like gender. The problem is the value I get only for option one, and when I check, I get warning like `[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id`. I need the value so I can passed it to database with ajax.

```js
$('#register').on('click',function(){
  var gender=$('#gender').val();
  console.log(gender);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" id="task-form">
   <table class="table">
    <tr>
       <td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male"> Male</td>
       <td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"> Female</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Submit" id="register">Register</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Do you know what I need to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute [***id***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, you can use *class* instead.

You can use the *name* attribute along with [**`:checked`**](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) as part of the selector.

```js
$('#register').on('click',function(){
  var gender=$('[name=gender]:checked').val();
  console.log(gender);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" id="task-form">
   <table class="table">
    <tr>
       <td><input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="male"> Male</td>
       <td><input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="female"> Female</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Submit" id="register">Register</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way to achieve it

```
$('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
```

```js
$('#register').on('click',function(){
  var gender= $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
  console.log(gender);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" id="task-form">
   <table class="table">
    <tr>
       <td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"> Male</td>
       <td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"> Female</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Submit" id="register">Register</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same `ID` for two different tags.

You can modify the `jQuery` function to use the name attribute to pull the value from like below

```
var gender = $("input[name = 'gender']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any two or more elements on a page cannot have the same **ID**.

You have given `id="gender"`into input fields.

You can give ids as `id="m"` (**or** `id="male"`) and `id="f"` (**or** `id="female"`)

Then you can user **name** attribute to get the value of the selected radio button.

In vanilla javascript

`var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked').value;`